# Android Studio complains duplicate class

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to generate an apk file but android studio is showing me the following error:

> Duplicate class
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient found in
>   modules classes.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0)
>   Duplicate class
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info found
>   in modules classes.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0)
>   Duplicate class
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$zza found in
>   modules classes.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0)

It was working previously. I totally did not make any changes to the code. Can anyone help?

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'


def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.step_by_step.virq"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }

    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1"
implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0"

if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Comment: Add ur build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Your version [**7.8.0**] of `play-services-analytics` is very old. Try to use latest one

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where I created a new project and added some old libraries.
Back when these libraries and other projects using them have been written, they were at some point migrated to AndroidX. If I recall correctly, the following lines were added at the `gradle.properties (Project Properties)` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

In my new project, the `android.enableJetifier=true` line was missing, which caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to the conflicts between firebase & google service dependencies. You have basically 2 type of solutions for this.

You can either change versions and keep doing that until you get the perfect working combination which is more time consuming or you can find a solution that works every time so you don't have to change the versions every time. You just use that solution whenever you get this error.

So, you need to use the updated method of injecting the firebase dependency as shown on the android developer site.

**Using firebase "bom"**

Put this line in your dependency :

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
```

Then, You can use any firebase dependency without specifying the versions, and it will work perfectly every time!

The final solution looks like this,

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
```

So now, it won't produce any duplication related errors with the play-services dependency.